# another '"java.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, environment-variables, flashdevelop, haxe, nme

As I have been struggling with this over two hours, I am desperately posting this question,

When I try to build a NME project in FlashDevelop, I get this error:

```
Running process: C:\Program Files (x86)\FlashDevelop\Tools\fdbuild\fdbuild.exe "C:\Users\KETAB\Desktop\SplashScreen\SplashScreen.hxproj" -ipc 41740bf7-6aa9-4825-9b1d-a8450386e5ad -version "2.10" -compiler "C:\Motion-Twin\Haxe" -library "C:\Program Files (x86)\FlashDevelop\Library" -target "android"
Building SplashScreen
haxelib run nme build C:\Users\KETAB\Desktop\SplashScreen\application.nmml android -debug
haxelib run hxcpp Build.xml haxe -Ddebug -Dandroid -Dcpp -Ddebug -Dhaxe_208 -Dhaxe_209 -Dhaxe_210 -Dmobile -Dnme -Dnme_install_tool -Dsys -Dtrue
'"java.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Build halted with errors (haxelib.exe).
```

Although, in the terminal, if I type java I get the friendly helper lines..

```
C:\Users\KETAB>java
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server       to select the "server" VM
    -hotspot      is a synonym for the "server" VM  [deprecated]
                  The default VM is server.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument

    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for m
ore details.
```

I have tried this in the environment variables:

```
PATH C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\bin
JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_13
```

How come I can call java inside the terminal, while FlashDevelop says that is not recognized as an internal or external command??

Any one can help?

Comment: I am assuming that `java.exe` is not properly configured in `Build.xml`.

Comment: Can you post your `Build.xml`?

Comment: I am not using custom build, I am on a nmml file, I solved the problem by installing Java Runtime 32, but now I got another error:Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\tools.jar, why its searching in jre7 ?!

Comment: You need to install jdk if you want access to tools.jar as far as I remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing Java Runtime 32, its important when using FlashDevelop

Comment: You can use the 64 bit version as well by defining JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME properly but FlashDevelop community recommends 32 bit.

Comment: What's the difference between JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME?

Comment: JDK_HOME is for Java Deevlopment Kit (JDK) aka JavaSE and JAVA_HOME works with both Java Runtime (JRE) and JDK if only one exists.

Answer (score 0):

if you have cygwin installed in the Windows Box, or using UNIX Shell then

```
Issue bash#which java
```

This will tell you whether java is in your classpath or NOT.